# NetLogo in Continuous Space

Tags: netlogo

I have trying find NetLogo Simulation of the famous Helbing Model 2000 to make my job easier. But I am surprised at it's unavailability presently.
Most forums I have asked tend to argue that NetLogo is aimed for discrete models and continuous space models are not well implemented in it.
I am just starting to make some continuous models, therefore I wish to ask what drawbacks exactly has when used to develop discrete models.

PS: Is Helbing 2000 model ever made in NetLogo?

Comment: I'm not very familiarized with continuos space models but there're a few examples of continuous models in NetLogo (Cellular Automata). So it should be good to code it, what's the issue tho?

Comment: I just thought it should be able in NetLogo, it's such a popular model. A reference model could be of great help. http://www.openabm.org/page/vote-models-you-would-see-replicated

Comment: There's an example code in the Model Library in NL, it's called CA Continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Well technically you're limited with a discrete model by the precision of your computer (i.e. number of decimal places it will go). There is a bit of a work around of sorts if your model has to act more continuous than discrete. As David mentioned, you can go here:

http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/CAContinuous

Basically it depends on what you're trying to model. If you want to see what happens when "prey" panics in the presence of the "predator", NetLogo is good enough. If you want to estimate what making 1,000,000 of your prey population more easily panicked would do, you might need to take a continuous approach.